# Using string value as variable in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to control the following plot by the variables xAxis and split

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(
  col1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4),
  col2 = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1),
  z = rnorm(6))

xAxis="col1"
split="col2"
```

The folowing example does work

```
df<-split(data, data[,xAxis])
p1 <- ggplot()
for(i in df){
 p1 <- p1 + geom_bar(data = i, aes(x=col1, y = ..count..), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
}
p1
```

but

```
df<-split(data, data[,xAxis])
p1 <- ggplot()
for(i in df){
 p1 <- p1 + geom_bar(data = i, aes(x=i[,xAxis], y = ..count..), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2)
}
p1
```

does not work. And with some other data but exactly the same function I got for the second e.g. the Error:

```
Error in data.frame(x = list(sec = c(40, 18, 5, 47, 50, 7, 9, 22, 27,  : 
  Argument used differnt number of rows: 707, 3938
```

Comment: There are many ways you can "control" a plot. Can you try to describe in greater detail what you wish to achieve in the end. Do any of [these examples](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_%28ggplot2%29/) look like what you have in mind?

Comment: `aes_string` is what you're looking for.  Specifically `aes_string(x=xAxis)`.

Comment: You may also let `ggplot` split your data: have a look at [`facet_grid`, e.g. here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_%28ggplot2%29/)

Comment: @Justin, how to call aes(x=col1, y = ..count..) as aes_string?